# Program skipping true if-statements, but executing false ones

Tags: c++, if-statement

Okay, so I'm (trying) to make a word guessing game, while also trying to learn about coding. My problem here is, that the program skips true if-statements and executes false ones. Here's a section:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Some more #include...*/

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int Lives = 5, Sel_Word, i;
        string Sel_Diff;

        /*Some more variables*/

        while(Lives >= 1)
        {
                cout << "Difficulty...";
                cin >> Sel_Diff;
                if  (Sel_Diff == "Very Easy")
                {

                        /*Executes game for that level*/

                }

                /*Gets skipped, when I enter "Very Easy" for
                some reason*/

                if (Sel_Diff == "Exit")
                {
                        break;
                }

                /*Works fine*/

                if (Sel_Diff == "Easy" || Sel_Diff == "Medium")

                /*Et cetera...*/

                {
                        cout << "\n\nDifficulty does not yet     exist!";
                }
                else
                {
                        cout << "\n\nDifficulty does not exist";
                }

                /*These two execute, when I enter 
                "Very Easy" for some reason*/

        }
}
```

Notes:
I looked to see if someone has the same problem, but I didn't find anyone, although I found a question about a false statement executing, which doesn't help me. Also, I don't know if this happens only in c++, haven't used c or c#.

Comment: `if  (Sel_Diff == "Very Easy"`` won't compile - it has a missing bracket - apart from that is this precisely the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Can you try the same thing after changing the string and removing the spaces. I.e. `VeryEasy`. (input the same way)

Comment: When you read input using the input operator `>>` it will stop reading at white-space, so you can't read multi-word inputs with only a single input operator.

Comment: Spelling mistake, it cannot be compiled without the ) and returns an error (expected ')'before '{' token)

Comment: Apart from the missing parenthesis, `Medium` is also undeclared. When posting "why doesn't this code work" questions, post the *real* code, copy/pasted from your editor.

Comment: You need double quotes around Medium

Comment: @WhozCraig I can't because I don't have internet on my PC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This condition

```
cin >> Sel_Diff;
if  (Sel_Diff == "Very Easy")
```

will never trigger because `operator>>` only reads one word at a time. So it stops after `Very`.

If you want to read more, like a whole line of input, you can use `getline(cin, Sel_Diff);`

Comment: The code was able to be compiled and did run, the spelling mistakes were just here, not in the actual code.